# How to convert wedge–dash structure into Fischer projection?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, notation

I am very confused when a compound with more than one chiral centre is given. How to find whether the two compounds are enantiomers or diasteromers?

Please also explain how to convert more than one chiral compound with wedge–dash structure to Fischer projection.

Comment: Where should i start?What are thoughts?what did you attempt?

Comment: Sir when chiral centre is given then i can convert by the method that one atoms below.or above the plane of paper are lie on horizontal line and other lie on same plane on a vertical but when it come to more than one chiral centre i am confuse .when question asks predict wether pair entaiomers or something

Comment: Could you edit your question and give an example that you attempted? Also, you are asking two questions, so you should probably post two questions. Otherwise, the title does not match the questions, and it would be difficult to find your second question.

Answer (score 6):

**Method 1**
[image]

**Method 2**

Quoting from

http://oscar.iitb.ac.in/OSCARPP/Chemistry/UploadedStoryboards/SCH023_3P0431Wedge-dash%20to%20Fischer.ppt

The following is conversion of molecules with two chiral centres from wedge to fischer projection yhrough a series of operations as shown below.

[image]

**Reference :**

http://oscar.iitb.ac.in/OSCARPP/Chemistry/UploadedStoryboards/SCH023_3P0431Wedge-dash%20to%20Fischer.ppt

Answer (score 0):

How to find whether the two compounds are enantiomers or diasteromers?

**Diastereomers** are stereoisomers that are **not mirror images** of one another and are **non-superimposable** on one another.$\ce{^1}$

**Enantiomers** are chiral molecules that are **mirror images of one another**. Furthermore, the molecules are **non-superimposable** on one another. This means that the molecules cannot be placed on top of one another and give the same molecule.$\ce{^2}$

The figure below will explain.

Further in diastereomers only part of the molecule is a mirror reflection.(circled in the image) ,while the other stereo-center is identical.

NOTE:Geometrical isomers are also diasetreisomers , but achiral.In the examples given below Diastereomers are chiral.

[image]

References:

1. http://www.chemeddl.org/resources/stereochem/definitions17.htm

2.http://www.chemeddl.org/resources/stereochem/definitions16.htm